# California resident, Delaware C-Corp - Taxes for 1-person software freelancer?

Tags: united-states, taxes, small-business, incorporating

I'm a one person software contractor / freelancer / app store developer who lives in California (although I spend most of my year traveling to other places).

I incorporated a Delaware c-corp earlier this year, because I was always told by VCs and such that this was the best route.

1) Supposedly this also means that I am free from having to pay California corporate taxes?

2) Or, does this mean I am required to pay both CA taxes and Delaware fees? (In this case, minimal, just a paid agent from incorporate.com)

3) Is there any benefit at all for me to be a Delaware C-Corp or should I dissolve and start over. Or just re-incorporate as California LLC

Answer (score 3):

> Supposedly this also means that I am free from having to pay
>   California corporate taxes?

Not in the slightest. Since you (the corporate employee) reside in CA - the corporation is doing business in CA and is liable for CA taxes.

> Or, does this mean I am required to pay both CA taxes and Delaware
>   fees? (In this case, minimal, just a paid agent from incorporate.com)

I believe DE actually does have corporate taxes, check it out. But the bottom line is yes, you're liable for both CA and DE costs of doing corporate business (income taxes, registered agents, CA corp fee, etc).

> Is there any benefit at all for me to be a Delaware C-Corp or should I
>   dissolve and start over. Or just re-incorporate as California LLC

Unless you intend to go public anytime soon or raise money from VCs/investors - there's no benefit whatsoever in incorporating in DE. You should seek a legal advice with an attorney, of course, since benefits are legal issues (usually related to choosing jurisdiction for litigation etc).

If you're a one-person freelancer, doing C-Corp was not the best decision as well. Tax-wise you'd be much better off with a S-Corp, or a LLC - both pass-through and have no (Federal) entity-level taxes. Corporate rates are generally higher than individual rates, and less deductions can be taken. In California, check with a CPA/EA licensed in the State, since both S-Corp and LLC would be taxed, and taxed differently.